# The closure of a graph is unique

Tags: graph-theory

The closure of a graph $G$ is defined to be the graph obtained from $G$ by recursively joining pairs of non-adjecent vertices whose degree sum is at least $n$, until no such pair exists [$n=|V(G)|$].

I want to prove that the closure is unique.

I tried to assume the claim is incorrect, so there exist $G_1$ and $G_2$, both closures of $G$ but there exists some edge $(a,b)$ in $G_1$ (WLOG) which doesn't belong to $G_2$.

By definition of closure we know that $d(a) + d(b) < n$ (in $G_2$).

I'm not sure how to proceed, can you please give me some clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us say that a nonadjacent vertex pair $\{u,v\}$ is *good* for the graph $G$ if there is a sequence of vertex pairs $\{u_1,v_1\},\dots,\{u_k,v_k\} = \{u,v\}$ such that $d(u_i) + d(v_i) \geq n$ in $G + \{u_1v_1,\dots,u_{i-1}v_{i-1}\}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq k-1$.

How can you (uniquely) describe the closure of $G$ in terms of good vertex pairs?

**Answer:**

> The closure is $G + \{uv : \{u,v\} \text{ is good}\}$.

This approach can be reformulated in terms of your proof attempt, but I find it cleaner this way.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, what's the connection between {u,v} and the sequence of pairs?

Comment: Maybe you can't add $uv$ directly to the graph, i.e. $d(u) + d(v) < n$ before adding the previous edges $u_1v_1, \dots u_{k-1}v_{k-1}$. In essence, you are iteratively adding all edges $xy$ with $d(x) + d(y) \geq n$. The good pairs are those edges that are added in this process after some iterations.

Comment: Oh, I missed the last case, where i = k-1. So now I need to show that your representation is the closure. Thank you!